# How to make water teleporter in bukkit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I have Bukkit server and i want to my world "Minigames": when played for example Tnt-spleef player fall down and teleported automaticly to edge of arena and spectate.
I know that vanilla minecraft commands won't help and i have tested it with Multiverse-portals, but teleportation works before the server is shut down or the Restart.
Have you any suggestions about other plugin that is lightweight and works as water teleporter?

image: [image: Ground water teleporter regions]

Comment: Nice looks a good mini-game.

Comment: You could do this in vanilla by checking the y coord of the player and then telporting them to a fixed location and setting their gamemode to spectator.

Comment: Have you tried a ton of trip wires connected to a command block?

Answer (score 1):

I think i have a good plugin for you.
It is called PortalCommands, which you can download here:
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/portalcommands/

You need worldedit for it, and you can make the portal almost any size you want!